# How to specifc std in vcproj

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have some Windows software, that I only build on a remote Windows VM. I have no GUI access to the remote or any other Windows machine.

I would like to specifc `/std:c++17` now. Reading through the vcproj docs, I could not yet find, where in that file I would add the option. Could anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the build is based on the `.vcxproj` project file (as opposed to an external `makefile` or other), the language conformance level is defined under `<ClCompile><LanguageStandard>` for each configuration. For example, to add [`/std:c++17`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2019) to the Release x64 build, insert (or modify) the following `<LanguageStandard>` line. Repeat for other configurations as applicable.

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <!-- other existing settings -->
      <LanguageStandard>stdcpp17</LanguageStandard>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```